# Geoexplorer cannot Save and Publish maps

Tags: boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I installed Geoexplorer 3.0.2 according to [instructions](https://github.com/opengeo/suite/tree/master/geoexplorer).
I also setup GEOEXPLORER_DATA in *web.xml* file and it seems that it works fine because `http://localhost:8080/geoexplorer/maps/?` returns:

```
{"maps":[]}
```

But when I'm trying to Save my map I get back the half link:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoexplorer/composer/
```

*Notice there is no **#maps/MapID** at the end of the above link,as it was supposed to be.*

Also when I'm trying to Publish my map I get the following link:

```
<iframe style="border: none;" height="400" width="600" src="http://localhost:8080/geoexplorer/viewer/#maps/undefined"></iframe>
```

Notice that instead of **MapID** at the end of the above link, it gives me the **undefined**

The directory GEOEXPLORER_DATA and geoexplorer.db have full permissions to tomcat7 user/group.
Is it an insertion problem in my db file? Is it a bug or something else?

If I run GeoExplorer in **development** mode (without setting any GEOEXPLORER_DATA directory), I have no problem. I can Save and Publish my maps. I only have that problem when I run it under **deployment** in a production environment (under tomcat7).

Maybe is a **GeoServer Proxy problem** because during debugging I get:

```
POST http://myexternal_IP:8080/geoexplorer/maps/ 401 (Unauthorized) GeoExplorer.js:396
    b.send GeoExplorer.js:396
    (anonymous function)
Trouble saving: {"error":"Not authorized"}
```

My configuration is the following:

I set up **Proxy Base URL** of Geoserver to `http://myexternal_IP/geoserver`
I also setup **Apache ProxyPass**:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
```

Finally, I **build the app** with:

```
ant -Dapp.proxy.geoserver=http://myexternal_IP/geoserver debug
```

But the problem still remains...

Comment: Which web browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 19.0 and Google Chrome 21.0.1180.89

Answer (score 1):

As Leonidas, I encountered absolutely identical problems.

After searching a lot of info in GeoExplorer/GeoServer/Tomcat/Java forums, I thought the problem might be related to...  GeoServer!

So, after the deployement of **the latest geoserver.war**, I was surprised to see that everything works OK!!!

Now I am able to **save** and **export** any kind of maps!

I think there are some incompatibilities between different geoserver and geoexplorer releases.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the tomcat user has write access to your `geoexplorer.db` file. If this does not help, use your browser's development console to inspect the network traffic to the `http://localhost:8080/geoexplorer/maps/` endpoint. The error message should give you a hint on what is wrong.

Comment: Yes tomcat7 user has rwx permissions. But using debug tools I get the following error:  `POST http://83.212.xxx.xxx:8080/geoexplorer/maps/ 401 (Unauthorized) GeoExplorer.js:396
b.sendGeoExplorer.js:396
(anonymous function)`